# How to section window in HaxeFlixel?

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I'd like to partition the window into a number of sections.  I want each section to have its own stuff going on, and sprites should not be able to leave the area.  What is the idiomatic way to do this in HaxeFlixel?

Comment: [Crossposted to haxeflixel forums](http://forum.haxeflixel.com/topic/811/how-to-section-the-window)